# CEF - Run window multiple times one after another

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a WinForm app that starts in background (loop in Program.cs). After receiving a message it shows Form with CEF browser in it

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    while(true){

        if(messageReceived()){
            if(Program.message == 200) {
                Application.Run(new Form());
            }
            else {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And window:

```
private CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser browserChrome;

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.browserChrome = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(String.Empty);
    this.browserChrome.Load("htp://www.google.pl");
}
```

It works for the first time, but after I close my Form, App starts to check for messages again and when I want to open my Form again, whole Exe crashes:
"ChromeApp stopped working"
Error occured in

libcef.dll, version: 3.2785.1482.0, time stamp: 0x57eb4d4e

Is it possible to run this Form twice with Chromium or not?

Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to use `Application.Run(new Form());`? Maybe `new form().Show()` would work for you instead? This will launch a new form, but not an entire new application.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it already - to be honest that was one of my first ideas, but nothing. I have come up with some "dirty" solution.

Just to explain, Cef.Initialize() is in my original code, I just forgot to put it in my example. I Modified my code a bit and it is working for now.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Cef.Initialize(new Cef.Settings());

    var chromeBrowser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(String.Empty);
    while(true){

        if(messageReceived()){
            if(Program.message == 200) {
                var form = new Form();
                form.ChromeBrowser = chromeBrowser;

                Application.Run(form);
            }
            else {
                Cef.Shutdown();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and window:

```
private CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser browserChrome;

public CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser ChromeBrowser {
    set {
        this.browserChrome = value;
    }
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.browserChrome.Load("htp://www.google.pl");
}
```

It keeps Chromium and everything that it needs alive and working whole time.

I think I'm gonna write a class to keep my Chromium in there so I won't have to pass it through forms when I need it somewhere deeper - some simple singleton, but that on monday.